# Python remove() modifies unintended list

Tags: python

```
x=['0100', '1111', '1001', '1011']
y=x
y.remove('0100')
print(x)
```

the code above returns:`['1111', '1001', '1011']`
I am a begginer programmer and I want to know why the `remove()` function also modifies the x list instead of the intended y list? The code is run in python 3.4.2. How do I fix this so that only the y list will be modified?

Comment: `y=x` does not copy the list. try `y=x[:]` or `y=list(x)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Try `id(x)` and `id(y)` to see that they reference the same object.

Comment: You have to learn what _reference_ is and what is difference between _mutable_ and _immutable_ types in Python. _list_ is mutable type, so assigning will create new reference to a new object

Comment: @Akavall: Python has more obvious way to do that: `y is x`.

Comment: @myaut, I think actually seeing memory address (OK identity of an object in python) helps the point sink. It helped me, when I was first learning this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you copied the **reference** of `x` into `y`.
you can create a copy by `y = list(x)`.

**for example:**

```
x=['0100', '1111', '1001', '1011']
y = list(x)
y.remove('0100')
print(x)
```

Comment: You may want to mention [Shallow and deep copy operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simple - x and y are not `lists`, they are just references to list. there is some point in memory containing list data and both x and y just know where it is. So when you do `y = x` and change list referenced by y, this change will be reflected at `print(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between the variable and the what this variable contains. 
With this:

```
x=['0100', '1111', '1001', '1011']
y=x
```

X and y are exactly the same, you have to copy x and make the assignation you can do it this way: `y=x[:]`, this code copy the content of x and assign it to y